# Issue with API Request Cycle

Tags: api, javascript

I have an issue to request the Cycle Number from [this API](https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?number=1&page=0). I don't understand how to use the map to get the data from the last cycle only.

```
 const ul2 = document.getElementById('Cycle');
  const url2 = 'https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?number=1&page=0';
  fetch(url2)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data){
      data.map(
      let span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = `${data.cycle}`;
      ul2.appendChild(span)   
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMXeYJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element returned from https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?number=1 is the data from the latest cycle.

HTML

```
<h1>Last Cycle</h1>
<div id="cycle"></div>
<div id="rollCount"></div>
<div id="rollTotal"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
const url = 'https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?number=1&page=0';
const cycleEl = document.getElementById('cycle')
const rollCountEl = document.getElementById('rollCount')
const rollTotalEl = document.getElementById('rollTotal')

fetch(url)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(([lastCycle]) => {
  cycleEl.innerText = lastCycle.cycle
  rollCountEl.innerText = lastCycle.roll_count
  rollTotalEl.innerText = lastCycle.roll_total
})
.catch(console.log);
```

https://codepen.io/RichardAyotte/pen/MxRWJG

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Javascript question then a Tezos question, but anyway;

```
 const ul2 = document.getElementById('Cycle');
  const url2 = 'https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?number=1&page=0';
  fetch(url2)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data){
    if (data.length > 0) {
      let span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = `${data[0].cycle}`;
      ul2.appendChild(span)
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If you ever get multiple items in the returned data array you need to sort the array before picking the correct element.

Comment: Thanks for you help but it doesn't work ! I try all the way possible ! Do you think I should better ask that on the JavaScript stackexchange ?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what you are trying to do. Did you try Richards answer above? 